# Why did we get 2 new mods?

Tags: support, election

RE:

> If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Firstly, this isn't to complain or criticise the election process or question the worthy winners of the election.   I wanted to know what are the reasons for acquiring 2 new moderators?  Have we lost 2 moderators in recent times?  Has there been an increase in site traffic?  Other reason(s)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some of the existing moderators' capacity to handle flags has reduced, and the moderation burden became too unevenly split. This was the situation as of May 30th, 2016:

[image]

We added two moderators to rebalance the workload.

Comment: Please notice that "Mod abuse (per unit of time)" is obviously a tongue-in-cheek way to express a number that is proxy for moderation activity that would take too long to explain otherwise. The terminology is vague on purpose.

Comment: And most likely much more complicated than the explanation of the said unit used in the graph.

Comment: This answer has 11 upvotes (as of now). MOD ABUSE ELEVEN!!!11!!!!!11!!!!